# How to programatically remove parent form taxonomy term?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I try to remove programatically all parents form my taxonomy terms. But I can't get it working. I tried this code:

```
$vid = 18; 
$tree = taxonomy_get_tree($vid); 
foreach ($tree as $term) {
   $term->parents = null;  # Does not work
   $status = taxonomy_term_save($term);
}
```

But after saving (although the function returns 2) the parents are still there. What is wrong?

Comment: By removing parents you want to make the list flat, all terms top level?

Comment: @Mołot Exactly, that's what I want to do. I hope to save some memory on bootsrap, if I only use flat terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`taxonomy_term_save()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_save/7) treats `null` as "do not change parent", and `0` means "this term does not have any parents". Also, property is named `parent`, not `parents`. Change

```
$term->parents = null;
```

to

```
$term->parent = 0;
```

and you're done.

Comment: Thank you for the super fast replay! But are you sure. I just tried, but it did not work out. I even tried to do something like `unset($term->parents); $term->parents = array();` But did not work neither.

Comment: @user5950 I linked function name to documentation. Seems you made a typo (and I copy-pasted it, sorry). It's parent, not parents.

Comment: Thank you. Don't now how that could happen. All my fault!